# Get the html content of Website Url in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I need to show to html by giving the website url . How to do i achieve this in react-native . I saw the many components that is not properly suited .

Comment: looking for an answer as well

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read about [webview](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html) on react native

I hope you get idea to solve your problem from this reference :)